# Array inside Firebase ref not accessible

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can anyone help me with this?

The Variable `dwn` is defined inside the `foreach` but my Firebase DB does not update.

The path is definitely correct.

What's my mistake?

Any help much appreciated!

```
 items.forEach(function (element) {
    console.log(dwn) // returns array like it should
    firebase.database().ref('vdemo/cities/' + city.toLowerCase() + "/categories/" + element.toLowerCase() + "/" + id).update({
       "img_paths": dwn // does to push to DB
        "category": element.toLowerCase() // defined and OK
    });

 });
```

The dwn array comes from here:

```
    dwn = [];


    function uploadImages (imageFile) {

        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(imageFile.name);
        var task = storageRef.put(imageFile);
        task.on('state_changed',
            function complete(){
                var downloadURL = task.snapshot.downloadURL;
                storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                    dwn.push(url);    
                 });

            }
        );
}
```

the array has this content:

[image]

Comment: Where's `dwn` from? Where is it undefined? Certainly not if you log it in that code, right? Is it "undefined" in Firebase?

Comment: Category is visible in the db but the dwn array is not

Comment: You'll have to show us where `dwn` comes from.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv updated the question

Comment: Isn't `storageRef.put` async? Meaning you have to wait for it to finish for `dwn` to contain all the data you need. You're probably not waiting and doing that update _before_.